# Не загружаются изображения Opencart

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, opencart

Есть OpenCart 2.0.2.0. Импортирую товары на сайт через модуль Import/Export. Все импортируется, все хорошо,НО, не загружаются изображения товаров! Пути прописаны правильно, в базе данных тоже все правильно прописано, но изображения всеравно нет! Имена изображений на английском языке, без символов и так далее. Просто не выводятся изображения. Что это может быть?

И еще, если я из ,базы возьму пути к картинке, **catalog/demo/products/OHMPD16.png** и вставлю вот так в адресную строку: **www.site.com/image/catalog/demo/products/OHMPD16.png**, то откроется картинка в полном размере. Значит она точно есть на сервере и она доступна для просмотра.

**Обновление**

В консоли вообще ничего кроме этого не пишется:

> util.js:208 Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#no-api-keys
>   util.js:208 Google Maps API warning: SensorNotRequired https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#sensor-not-required

Я уверен что папка куда я забросил изображения верна. Может есть какие-то ограничения в Opencart? Потому что когда я все товары удаляю, и загружаю те же самые, но в количестве 20 штук, изображения появляются. А когда 1600, то ничего не происходит

Comment: а какой адресс картинки на сайте?

Answer (score 1):

Изображения для товаров, категорий и т.д. берутся не напрямую, а из кэша. Туда они складываются уже нарезанные под требуемы размеры (миниатюры, большое изображение товара, банер и т.д.). Например, если Вы загрузили для товара картинку `iphone_1.png` , то большое изображения товара в карточке будет `example.com/image/cache/catalog/demo/iphone_1-500x500.png`
Проверьте, у Вас в директории /image/cache/ файлы есть, права на папку и файлы? Посмотрите в `config.php` директория для изображений правильная указана? Ну и посмотрите в консоли браузера по каким путям изображения ищутся.

Answer (score 0):

Буквально недавно была похожая проблема. Импортировал картинки из 1С. Оказалось что к имени файла картинки в конце добавлялся лишний пробел.
У вас вероятно то же самое.